# Click ComboButton item with Selenium

Tags: python, python-3.x, selenium, selenium-webdriver

I am trying to preform a simple click, but cannot find out what way to find it due to the type of element it is.

```
<div class="active">
    <div class="action-title">Reconcile All</div>                           
    <div class="action-description">Reconcile all IPv4 addresses</div>                              
</div>

<div class="active">
    <img src="/images/icons/small/checks.gif" border="0">
</div>
```

I have tried doing it several ways. Such as,

```
driver.find_elements_by_link_text("Reconcile All").click()
WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.LINK_TEXT, "Reconcile All"))).click()
```

I even tried based of the icon

```
driver.find_element_by_xpath("//*[contains(@src,'/images/icons/small/checks.gif')]").click()
```

Thanks in advance for any help

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Div element can't click using `link_text` try Use following xpath and Webdriverwait to click.

```
WebDriverWait(driver,20).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.XPATH,"//div[@class='active']//div[@class='action-title'][contains(.,'Reconcile All')]"))).click()
```

Comment: Hot damn, nice an easy. Thanks so much. Quick question for learning, it looks like using the xpath method, its looking for the full path to the item to be clicked, rather then just a simple id/name? Also, I will mark as solved when able.

Comment: The element you have provided there is no name or id attribute.However it always good to use `xpath` or `css selector`.